# Changing IdentityUser.Id Type to Guid Causes Migrations to Fail

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core, .net-core, entity-framework-migrations, asp.net-core-identity

I have changed the type of the `IdentityUser.Id` property from `string` to `Guid` and added a relationship to a base class `LogEntry`, which has derived classes `JournalEntry` and `Weight Entry`.

When I attempt to `Update-Database`, I get the following error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Column 'AspNetUsers.Id' is not the same data type as referencing column 'LogEntries.ApplicationUserId' in foreign key 'FK_LogEntries_AspNetUsers_ApplicationUserId'. Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

Entity Framework should be creating the `AspNetUsers` table with an `Id` field of type `uniqueidentifier`, but it is not. It's creating it with `nvarchar(450)`.

I have included relevant source code below:

**ApplicationUser.cs**

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<Guid>
{
    public ApplicationUser()
        : base()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
    }

    public virtual ICollection<LogEntry> LogEntries { get; set; }
}
```

**LogEntry.cs**

```
public abstract class LogEntry
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime CreatedDt { get; set; }

    public virtual Guid ApplicationUserId { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
}
```

**JournalEntry.cs**

```
public class JournalEntry : LogEntry
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

**JournalEntry.cs**

```
public class WeightEntry : LogEntry
{
    public short Kilograms { get; set; }
}
```

**ApplicationDbContext.cs**

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole<Guid>, Guid>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    DbSet<JournalEntry> JournalEntries { get; set; }
    DbSet<WeightEntry> WeightEntries { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>(x =>
        {
            x.HasMany(y => y.LogEntries)
                .WithOne(y => y.ApplicationUser)
                .HasForeignKey(y => y.ApplicationUserId)
                .HasPrincipalKey(y => y.Id)
                .IsRequired();
        });

        builder.Entity<LogEntry>(x =>
        {
            x.ToTable("LogEntries");

            x.HasOne(y => y.ApplicationUser)
                .WithMany(y => y.LogEntries)
                .HasForeignKey(y => y.ApplicationUserId)
                .HasPrincipalKey(y => y.Id)
                .IsRequired();
        });

        builder.Entity<JournalEntry>(x =>
        {
            x.ToTable("JournalEntries");
        });

        builder.Entity<WeightEntry>(x =>
        {
            x.ToTable("WeightEntries");
        });
    }
}
```

**Startup.cs** ConfigureServices

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole<Guid>>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext, Guid>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```